# Re-install Mac mini Server

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac-mini, formatting

My friend gave me Mac mini Server saying its Mavericks. When I switch it on I see 2 hard drives only and no operating system. I tried to use my Apple ID but it doesn't work. In disk utility I saw 1st hard drive has partition named "os" which I am not able to delete. How do I completely format both the hard drives and re-install Mavericks on that. I have a very slow internet and I don't have another mac, of course I have Linux and Windows dual boot machine.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the setup!

Comment: STOP, you can not get Mavericks installer any more (unless you already have it). Tell us bit more about the partitions (like size ect). There might be a OS on it already or the OS Recovery partition which is hidden and about 6050 Meg size, that you could use to restore OS. Also you could try to booth with cmd+r.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the friend what is going on?

Comment: My mac mini model is A1347. Yes, there is 1 partition see in 1st hard drive which I am not able to delete. The machine is not booting to operating system. I am completely novice to mac even if I am a very experienced Linux admin. My friend told while giving it to me this is Mavericks and then he is not answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we (and possibly you yourself as well) do not know what type of Mac Mini Server hardware you have, you can check this at the following Apple websites by using the serial number of your computer found at the underside:

- [Check Your Service and Support Coverage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do)
- [Tech Specs](https://support.apple.com/specs) (click on "Browse by product")

Respecting that you stated that you have a slow Internet connection, keep in mind that Mac OS X 10.7 Lion and later (Mavericks included) needs to be downloaded from the Internet, which is about 5 GB for each OS (plus 2 GB for the server extension in case of OS X 10.7 Lion).  The Mac Mini Server being a small computer, you can try to bring it to a friend to download it there, if they have a faster connection.

---

Nevertheless, here are some options for you:

For a **Mac Mini Server (Mid 2010) or before**, try one of the following options:

1. Use the installation media which came with the Mac (e.g. Mac OS X Server 10.6) to install the OS again (if you do not have an optical drive with it, you will need to have a different Mac sharing its optical drive or try to clone the disc to a USB thumb drive)
2. If a later version of Mac OS X is installed, you could use the built-in Recovery HD to install that version of Mac OS X the Recovery HD was created for (you will need to have obtained that version with your Apple ID or it will not work to authenticate the install).

For a **Mac Mini Server (Mid 2011) or later**, try the following option:

At startup, hold down Cmd+Alt+R to bypass any built-in recovery system and boot from the Internet Recovery (about 350-480 MB download).

This will give you the option to install the original OS which came with that Mac Mini Server.  Since that version is hardware-bound, no Apple ID is required to install it.

---

Once installed, you need to do the following to use Mavericks (or later):

- update the system to the latest version, then

  - if you own Mavericks already, download it from the list of purchases from the App Store
  - if you do not own it, you can download the latest version of OS X, which is Yosemite

Comment: Server extension 2 GB for Lion? Isn't it just ~250 MB for Lion Server? I don't remember exactly.

Comment: For Lion Server only, the actual OS will be converted into the server environment. This conversion asks to download a bit more than 2 GB of data once. If I recall right, the Lion Server.app itself was just 18-35 MB or so. All Lion updates after the conversion need to be for the server environment rather than the client environment. OS X 10.8 and later do not convert the base OS anymore, but the Server.app was larger (between 200-300 MB).

Comment: My MacMini model is A1347 which is Late 2012. I started it pressing Cmd+Alt+R as you recommended. It worked, connected to internet and downloaded Mountain Lion. I installed it and then upgraded it to Yosemite. Million thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

In disk utility via safe mode, you should be able to format it completely by wiping the disk.

Then after wiping the disk, boot into a DVD or USB of OS X and reformat from there.

Comment: how is he going to get the Mavericks on USB?

Comment: If the OP has a USB stick, and a copy of Mavericks from his friend, then it is possible. If not, you can always do the Yosemite install upgrade.

Comment: I do not have copy of any mac operating system. I will be thankful to you if you can tell me how can I get it. My friend is also not replying.